# Unity 2D Melee Combat System

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

i am a beginner game devepoler and i want to make a 2D action platformer game. I am trying to make a fluent combat system. I have researched this a lot but everywhere i found the same piece of code but it seems buggy and not reliable to me; for example it's damaging always twice, sometimes it doesnt respond to the key, when you held down the key its spamming etc. So i need a cleaner or better code, can you help me?

Weapon Script:

```
    private float timeBtwAttack;
    public float startTimeBtwAttack;

    public Transform attackPos;
    public float attackRange;
    public LayerMask whatIsEnemies;
    public int damage = 40;
    int steal = 20;
    public PlayerHealth playerHealth;

    void FixedUpdate()
    {
        if(timeBtwAttack <= 0){
            if(Input.GetKey(KeyCode.F)){
                Collider2D [] enemiesToDamage = Physics2D.OverlapCircleAll(attackPos.position, attackRange, whatIsEnemies);
                for (int i = 0; i < enemiesToDamage.Length; i++)
                {
                    enemiesToDamage[i].GetComponent<EnemyHealth>().TakeDamage(damage);
                }
                playerHealth.LifeSteal(steal);
            }

            timeBtwAttack = startTimeBtwAttack;
        }else{
            timeBtwAttack -= Time.deltaTime;
        }
    }
```

Enemy Health Script:

```
    public int maxHealth = 100;
    int currentHealth;

    void Start()
    {
        currentHealth = maxHealth;
    }

    public void TakeDamage(int damage)
    {
        currentHealth -= damage;
        Debug.Log("Damage Taken");

        if(currentHealth <= 0)
        {
            Die();
        }
    }

    void Die(){
        Debug.Log("Enemy Died");
    }
```

I have tried lots of different tutorials but everytime it was almost always the same piece of code.

Comment: Change `FixedUpdate` to `Update`.  `FixedUpdate` runs at a specific rate and is used for physics interactions.  `Input` works best in `Update` because it runs each frame.

Answer (score 0):

The difference between Update and FixedUpdate is how often these functions are executed.
As the name implies, FixedUpdate executes at fixed intervals. You can adjust this interval in the project physics settings.
However, the update function is called every frame when it is updated. So it is directly related to the frame rate, so the time interval here is not constant. For example. If the frame rate is 30fps, that means it updates every 33 milliseconds (1000 / 30). The reason it's not constant is because the game may experience lag and frame rate drops.
As a rule of thumb, you generally want to do all physics updates in the FixedUpdate function.